# Edit values of a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a `csv` file that looks like below

[image]

I want to add `30` to all the values in this , so that it could become like this,
[image]

I checked the `csv` module and tried to iterate it like below,

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open('myfile.csv'), delimiter=',')
for line in file:
    print(line[0])
```

It gives me the values of first `row` including the `header` which is a `string` so i cannot add `30` to it,how do i neglect it and add `30` to all other `values` i am not sure how to manipulate this, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your CSV as text?

Comment: @RoadRunner https://pastebin.com/raw/euWUD2Jx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really simple with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv).

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
df[["a", "b"]] += 30 # add 30 to columns a and b
df.to_csv("added30.csv")
```

Comment: What if a `column` has `string`

Comment: I edited my answer to only add 30 to columns a and b.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use a boolean flag to keep track of when the first line has been read:

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open('content.csv'), delimiter=',')
first_line = True
for line in file:
    if first_line:
        first_line = False  
    else:
        print(line[0])
```

An alternative is to get each line using [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open('content.csv'), delimiter=',')

try:
  next(file)    # Skip the first line
  while True:
    line= next(file)
    print(line[0])
except StopIteration:
  print("No more content")
```